# How to give a name to test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, integration-testing, django-testing

How do I give a name to unit test in Django?

With RSpec I would do something like

```
it 'has a name!' do
  # do something
end
```

But is it possible with Django so I can see normal names in PyCharm instead of this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a comment above the method name `# ...` and set the the test suite verbosity to 2. This will print a description along with the test like so:

`<test name>
test that so and so happens ... ok`

Comment: How to be with spacebars and case?

Comment: @ViktorDanilov forgot that Test Suites allow comments at the top. I updated my answer